# Duplicates in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to do the query directly a Magento database in MySQL but it gives me duplicates. Could you please help me?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
`catalog_product_entity`.`sku`
, `catalog_product_flat_1`.`name`
, `catalog_product_entity_text`.`value` AS `description`
, `catalog_product_flat_1`.`url_key`
, `catalog_product_flat_1`.`small_image`
, `catalog_product_flat_1`.`price`
, `catalog_product_flat_1`.`special_price`
, `catalog_product_flat_1`.`designer_value`
, `catalog_product_flat_1`.`color_value`
FROM
`ac_magento_gold`.`catalog_product_flat_1`
INNER JOIN `ac_magento_gold`.`catalog_product_entity` 
    ON (`catalog_product_flat_1`.`entity_id` = `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`) AND (`catalog_product_entity`.`sku` = `catalog_product_flat_1`.`sku`) AND (`catalog_product_flat_1`.`sku` NOT REGEXP '(SZ|SIZE|GIFT)')
INNER JOIN `ac_magento_gold`.`catalog_product_entity_text` 
    ON (`catalog_product_entity_text`.`entity_id` = `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`) AND (`catalog_product_entity_text`.`attribute_id`= 61)
INNER JOIN `ac_magento_gold`.`cataloginventory_stock_item` 
    ON (`cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id` = `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`) AND (`cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id` = `catalog_product_flat_1`.`entity_id`) AND (`catalog_product_entity_text`.`entity_id` = `cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id`) AND (`cataloginventory_stock_item`.is_in_stock = 1) LIMIT 6;
```

Comment: Duplicates *how*? The same `sku`, the same `name`? With the `DISTINCT` keyword, you're preventing the entire row from having duplicates - not individual fields within a row. What data are you receiving and what do you expect/want?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple websites or stores (or even stock_id), that could be the reason you are getting duplicates. You need to specify the relevant store_id or website_id or stock_id in your joins.

For example,

```
INNER JOIN `ac_magento_gold`.`catalog_product_entity_text` 
ON (`catalog_product_entity_text`.`entity_id` = `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`) 
AND (`catalog_product_entity_text`.`attribute_id`= 61)
```

should be

```
INNER JOIN `ac_magento_gold`.`catalog_product_entity_text` 
ON (`catalog_product_entity_text`.`entity_id` = `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`) 
AND (`catalog_product_entity_text`.`attribute_id`= 61)
AND `catalog_product_entity_text`.`store_id` = 0
```

or whatever your store_id is. Actually, the query makes even more sense (to me at least) with the parentheses rearranged like so:

```
INNER JOIN `ac_magento_gold`.`catalog_product_entity_text` 
ON (
`catalog_product_entity_text`.`entity_id` = `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` 
AND `catalog_product_entity_text`.`attribute_id`= 61
AND `catalog_product_entity_text``.store_id` = 0
)
```

You might also have to rewrite the following:

```
INNER JOIN `ac_magento_gold`.`cataloginventory_stock_item` 
ON (`cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id` = `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`)
AND (`cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id` = `catalog_product_flat_1`.`entity_id`)
AND (`catalog_product_entity_text`.`entity_id` = `cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id`) 
AND (`cataloginventory_stock_item`.is_in_stock = 1)
```

to:

```
INNER JOIN `ac_magento_gold`.`cataloginventory_stock_item` 
ON (`cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id` = `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`
AND `cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id` = `catalog_product_flat_1`.`entity_id`
AND `catalog_product_entity_text`.`entity_id` = `cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id` 
AND `cataloginventory_stock_item`.is_in_stock = 1
AND `cataloginventory_stock_item`.`stock_id` = 1)
```

again, depending on which stock_id you are interested in. As far as I know, catalog_product_entity only contains one of each entity_id, so no website_id, store_id, or stock_id has to be specified. I also believe that catalog_product_flat_1 is specific to one store_id or website_id or something, but I am not sure.

Comment: Hi The Phil Lee, Thanks a lot for your help. Your solution worked like a charm. Here is the code for future reference.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT catalog_product_entity.sku, catalog_product_flat_1.name, catalog_product_entity_text.value, catalog_product_flat_1.url_key, catalog_product_flat_1.small_image, catalog_product_flat_1.price, catalog_product_flat_1.special_price, catalog_product_flat_1.designer_value, catalog_product_flat_1.color_value, catalog_product_flat_1.short_description FROM ac_magento_gold.catalog_product_flat_1 INNER JOIN ac_magento_gold.catalog_product_entity ON (catalog_product_flat_1.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id)

Comment: AND (catalog_product_entity.sku = catalog_product_flat_1.sku) AND (catalog_product_flat_1.sku NOT REGEXP '(SZ|SIZE|GIFT)') INNER JOIN ac_magento_gold.catalog_product_entity_text ON (catalog_product_entity_text.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id AND catalog_product_entity_text.attribute_id= 61 AND catalog_product_entity_text.store_id = 1)

Comment: INNER JOIN ac_magento_gold.cataloginventory_stock_item ON (cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id AND cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id = catalog_product_flat_1.entity_id AND catalog_product_entity_text.entity_id = cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id AND cataloginventory_stock_item.is_in_stock = 1 AND cataloginventory_stock_item.stock_id = 1);

Comment: Glad I could help. If you're satisfied, could you please accept the answer?